# what to include for JavaScriptConverter

Tags: .net, vb.net

Can someone tell me what I should include to write custom JavaScriptConverter class?  I currently get a not defined error when inheriting it.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Collections


Public Class CustomClass
    Inherits JavaScriptConverter       'Error here
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx):

> When you inherit from JavaScriptConverter, you must override the following members:
>
> Deserialize
>
> Serialize
>
> SupportedTypes

You need to make sure you've implemented all of these members.

Comment: I would implement them but my custom class is throwing an error when inheriting JavaScriptConverter.

Comment: Have you included the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace in your code?

Comment: It say that class does not have any public member or does not exist, althought I already reference system.web

Comment: What if you explicitly add the whole path: `Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization`

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and it say System.Web.Script.Serialization does not exist or have no public members.

Comment: You say you've added the reference as well. Did you Right click on `References` and add the `System.Web` assembly?

Comment: Oh I think I know, it's reference 2.0 version of .net framework.

Comment: OK NVM, I can't use it because the project is built on .net 2.0